# How to load a second .qml file in BB 10 cascade

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

What I want is, for a button (in *one.qml*) click load a separate ***.cpp*** file (*second.cpp*) and in that ***.cpp*** file, call the ***second.qml*** file. How can I do that using ***BB10 C++*** coding. But not using *QML* coding. I have done it with QML coding BUT that is NOT what I want.

If I compare with Android development, from one Activity we call a second Activity which has a separate .xml file. That's the exact thing I want to test here in BB10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load a new QML document from C++, you have to use something like that:

```
bb::cascades::QmlDocument *qml = bb::cascades::QmlDocument::create("asset:///yourSecondFile.qml");
// You can define properties for your page
qml->setContextProperty("_propertyName", yourObject);
bb::cascades::Page *secondPage = qml->createRootObject();
```

See the [`QmlDocument`](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__qmldocument.html) documentation for a complete explanation of what you can do with your document.

So, now, you have your [`Page`](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__page.html) (or any other component). You'll need to push it, for example, on a [`NavigationPane`](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__navigationpane.html). You can do this that way:

```
// Create a back button
bb::cascades::ActionItem* backAction = bb::cascades::ActionItem::create()
    .title(tr("Previous page"))
    .imageSource(QUrl("asset:///back.png"))
    .onTriggered(navigationPane, SLOT(pop())
);

// Push the page
navigationPane->push(page
    .paneProperties(bb::cascades::NavigationPaneProperties::create()
        .backButton(backAction)
    )
);
```

Comment: Yes, this is working. I don't wan to use ActionItem either. I wanted to do it for a button click event. So what I did was inside the click event I call a function in my C++ code which will call my second source file constructor. Inside that constructor I call your first code snippet. Then it worked after some little changes. Thanks.